Cytoscape context menu library not working on mobile (only on desktop)
I'm using Cytoscape to visualize graphs in my Next.js app. I also just included the Cytoscape Context Menus library to show a context menu when right-clicking a node. On the desktop, this works all perfectly fine.
However, on mobile, clicking/tapping context menu items does nothing. The context menu itself appears, but I cannot click any menu item. Nothing happens. The menu items do not even change the background color when I tap them (which should be the case based on the stylesheet I use).
How do I approach this problem? What are comment case that something (e.g., events?) are working on the desktop but not on mobile?

Having the same problem. This extention seems to be not build for mobile. I stumbled across this alternative: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu. Have not tried it but looks suitable for mobile.

@JulianKarch Good to know that I'm not the only one face this issue. I've ended up writing my own component for the context menu. Since it does not have to be as flexible as a library, it's actually not much effort.
